# How can i add a column that has the same value

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to add a new Column to my dataset but when i did the  column only had 1 index
is there a way to make one value be in al indexes in a column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('file_1.json', lines=True)
df2 = pd.read_json('file_2.json', lines=True)
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2])
df3 = df.loc[:, ['renderedContent']]
görüş_column = ['Milet İttifakı']
df3['Siyasi Yönelim'] = görüş_column
```

Comment: The value of `görüş_column` is `['Milet İttifakı']` - a list with a single string item. Are you trying to fill every row in the `'Siyasi Yönelim'` column of `df3` with that string, or with that list? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, this could be your possible solution:-

You have mentioned these lines of code:-

```
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2])
df3 = df.loc[:, ['renderedContent']]
```

You can modify them into

```
   df3 = pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)  ## axis=1 means second dataframe will add to columns, default value is axis=0 which adds to the rows
```

Second point is,

```
df3 = df3.loc[:, ['renderedContent']]
```

I think you want to write this one , instead of `df3=df.loc[:,['renderedContent']]`.

Hope it will solve your problem.